# question about product of monotonic functions

Tags: calculus

What would be the multiplication product of monotonically decreasing function with a monotonically increasing function?
Tried to prove it by definition of monotonically dec./inc. but without any hope

As i understand the product is not(!) monotonic...

Comment: Well, if the product would be non-monotonic, you might start with some easy monotonic functions and see if you can find an increasing and decreasing function such that the product is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Note that $-x^2= (-x) \cdot x$ is not monotonic although it is the product of two monotonic functions. Since this was a very easy example, you can see that nothing can be said in general. Things chance if we assume that functions have constant sign.

Answer (score 1):

consider the lines $y=1+x$ and $y=1-ax$. The first is increasing, the second decreasing for $a>0$. At $x=1$ the value of the product is $2(1-a)$ which, depending on $a$, can be smaller, equal or greater than $1$.

Thus in general, your question does not have a good answer.